# table does not exist error during execution on powercenter workflow

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

During execution of workflow, I am getting below error while inserting the data in the table (TARGET), whereas when I am connecting same database user then I am able to insert the data, but powercenter is throwing the below error.

I have already created the synonym as well as given all the access.

```
Severity    Timestamp    Node    Thread    Message Code    Message

ERROR    23/05/2015 20:55:59    node01_CSADevelopment    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8229    Database errors occurred:

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Database driver error...

Function Name : Prepare DPL

SQL Stmt : INSERT INTO TARGET(ID,NAME)  VALUES ( ?, ?)

Oracle Fatal Error

Database driver error...

Function Name : Execute Multiple

SQL Stmt : INSERT INTO TARGET(ID,NAME)  VALUES ( ?, ?)

Oracle Fatal Error
```

Please assist.

Comment: looking at the sql stmt; maybe you need to specify the table owner/prefix, so it gets something like `yourdatabasename.TARGET` instead of just `TARGET`

Comment: I am not giving that...Informatica is automatically generating the SQL

Comment: yes but there are properties to specify the owner or table prefix so informatica knows what to generate..  eg. you can specify these properties in your session properties see [this](https://community.informatica.com/thread/31960#63425)

Answer (score 0):

someone is running or finished running a DDL statement on the table and have not committed. Identify that oracle session and kill it or you can commit that transaction or wait until the timeout expires on that table.